# How to use regex to test variable in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to test if a script argument is only composed of letters.
here is the script :

```
 BEGIN {
        VALUE=ARGV[1];
        if (VALUE ~ /[A-Za-z]/) {
           print VALUE " : Ok only letters";
        }
        print VALUE;
}
```

it seems that it matches every string with at least one letter :

```
tchupy@rasp:~$ awk -f s.awk file 111
value = 111
tchupy@rasp:~$ awk -f s.awk file  @@@
value = @@@
tchupy@rasp:~$ awk -f s.awk file  aaa
aaa : Ok only letters
value = aaa
tchupy@rasp:~$ awk -f s.awk file  1a1
1a1 : Ok only letters
value = 1a1
tchupy@rasp:~$ awk -f s.awk file  a1a
a1a : Ok only letters
value = a1a
tchupy@rasp:~$ awk -f s.awk file  1@1
value = 1@1
```

I tried to use the *match()* function, but I've got *a syntax error at or near [* when I try to use [A-Za-z] regex.

Thx

Comment: If you say you want to test a script argument, are you only using `awk` to test the content of a shell variable? Can you identify your shell, as there may be other possibilities. Apart from that, please add the failing `awk` program and the exact command line you used to call it.

Comment: Try replacing the regular expression from one that matches a letter *anywhere* in the variable to one that matches letters throughout, e.g. `/^[A-Za-z]+$/` ?  Or, for greater readability, `/^[[:alpha:]]+$/`

Comment: Note that `:alpha` covers Unicode, e.g. matches `Ð`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test will be true if the variable contains at least one character from your character class. To test if the variable *only* contains characters in your character class, you need to match from the beginning (`^`) to the end of the script:

```
BEGIN {
    VALUE=ARGV[1];
    if (VALUE ~ /^[A-Za-z]+$/) {
       print VALUE " : Ok only letters";
    }
    print VALUE;
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
BEGIN {
    print ARGV[1] ": " (ARGV[1] ~ /^[A-Za-z]+$/ ? "OK" : "BAD")
}
```

Comment: Or an inverted test with `[^A-Za-z]` to test for a single non-letter.

Comment: perfect, I tried with ^ & $ but I don't know how I missed it.. your 2nd form is nice ! Thank you

Comment: @Kusalananda, with gawk at least, bytes that don't form part of valid characters will match neither `[A-Za-z]` nor `[^A-Za-z]`, compare `awk 'BEGIN{if (ARGV[1] ~ /^[A-Za-z]+$/) print "ok"}' $'\200\200'` with `awk 'BEGIN{if (ARGV[1] !~ /[^A-Za-z]/) print "ok"}' $'\200\200'` in a UTF-8 locale for instance. (there's also the special case of the empty string)

Comment: The list of characters matched by `[A-Za-z]` will also vary greatly with the locale, OS, `awk` implementation and version thereof.

Comment: @Tchupy: Notwithstanding that you have accepted an answer, using a Bash test will save loading and executing a 600KB process for the sake of checking a few bytes. `[[ $1 =~ ^[[:alpha:]]+$ ]] && echo Yes || echo No`.